# Joining parent and child, and only display one record per parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm wondering if T-SQL can yield a result like in the table on the picture, using only SQL and/or some other extra functions. Or even not using cursors if is possible.

Please notice that for records two and three there is no values displayed for the parent record. They are only visible in the first one.

This is not a left or right outer join, where you get a null value for each value that has no match on the second table. In this case I'm getting those records, but I don't want to show them again and again.

[image: This is an example of the result that I want to get.]

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Please read & act on [mcve]. But--This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LAG` to look into the previous row:

```
select
  case when parentid = lag(parentid) over (order by parentid, childid)
       then parentid end as parentid,
  case when parentid = lag(parentid) over (order by parentid, childid)
       then parentname end as parentname,
   childid,
   childname,
   childvalue
from ...
order by parentid, childid;
```

Comment: I'll add the standard caveat that using your database to handle formatting seems like a really bad idea, but this is a great use of the lag() windowing function.

Comment: @Stuart Ainsworth: I agree. This is something I wouldn't do in SQL, but in the app or Website instead.

Answer (score 2):

Generally this is something handled in a reporting tool. If you must...

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by ParentID order by ChildID) as rn
    from T t
)
select *, case when rn = 1 then 'First' else '' end as ShowFirst
from data;
```